# OpenCSV vs FlatFileItemReader Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

What is the best way to read a `csv` file with Spring Batch OpenCSV or FlatFileItemReader? OpenCSV seems provide more capabilities on columns filtering.
Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: I was using `OpenCSV` to read a file and it worked fine. After I decided to use `FlatFileItemReader` and I am facing some issues and exceptions.

```
org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException: Parsing error at line: 

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'xxx' of bean class [xxx.Record]: Duplicate match with distance <= 5 found for this property in input keys:..
```

This not all the log, but this is the main exceptions I have. The `Duplicate match exception` is a bit confusing because I don't have duplicate record in the file.
Please, any help and `explanation` will be welcome.

Comment: Technically you can use any CSV reader instead of FlatFileItemReader. Just keep in mind FlatItemReader provides quite basic features such as encoding, lineMapper, linesToSkip, callback, lineTokenizer. If you found the current implementation is not enough for you, you can inherite FlatFileItemReader with more features

Comment: `OpenCSV seems provide more capabilities on columns filtering`. Can you elaborate on this? What can OpenCSV do that the `FlatFileItemReader` can't?.

Comment: They have the same capabilities I guess, but OpenCSV is more easy to learn and understand.

Comment: It seems to work now. I will do other tests to confirm. I have implemented `FieldSetMapper` to map the fields. Should we prefer  `FieldSetMapper` instead of  `BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper`?